# Rails5: partial render is looking for file in wrong location

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a method that makes a bunch of variables and ends with a call to render a partial...

```
  def add_shift 
...
    render :partial => 'assignments/edit'
  end
```

But when this page tries to render it gives me this gnarly error...

```
Missing partial volunteer_events/_editform_perfect, application/_editform_perfect with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:raw, :erb, :html, :builder, :ruby, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:
  * "/home/fonso/back-expirement/app/views"
```

this is the code for the breaking view...

```
<div class="modal fade" id="edit_event">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <div class="col-sm-8 left border-right">
          <h4 class="modal-title">Edit Assignment</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 right d-flex flex-row">
          <h4 class="modal-title">Who's Working</h4>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        </div>
      </div>       
        <%= render 'editform_perfect', assignment: @assignment %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The partial is located assignments/_edit.html
and assignments/_editform_perfect

So why am I getting this interesting error and how can I fix it so I see the partials?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the error message, it appears you're rendering the view from a controller `volunteer_events_controller`. So when you attempt to render the partial `editform_perfect` it will by default look in `views/volunteer_events/` directory.

You'll need to provide the path to the partial in the view.

`<%= render partial: 'assignments/editform_perfect'.... %>`